# Best way to specify local inputs and S3 inputs without modifying rules?

Tags: snakemake

I have a snakemake workflow that runs on a local HPC. I also want to use this workflow on AWS using boto to push files to and from S3 as needed. This circumvents IO issues when used in conjunction with --no-shared-fs. I was thinking the best way to do this was just using --default-remote-provider S3 & --default-remote-prefix to specify the bucket name. However, when this option gets invoked, it appends the S3.remote & bucket prefix to all the inputs. This includes executable programs such as: bwa, samtools, bedtools, etc. When boto tries to download these programs using boto, it doesn't keep executable permissions.

Is there a good way to specify "local" inputs vs S3 inputs without having to modify the rules? This way I can keep only 1 version of the workflow if I need to change/improve it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enclose the local files with local(...), analogous to the way to mark temp files. This way, they will be excluded from default remote application.

Note that tools should usually not be input or output files. Consider using the snakemake conda integration and bioconda for software deployment and specification: 
http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#integrated-package-management